# solve $\sin(2x)=0.3$

Tags: trigonometry

when I searched for the solution of $\sin(2x) =0.3$, I was very confused when finding $x=0.1524+n\pi$ where $n=0,+1,-1,+2,-2,..$ is the answer.

I know the following:

- $2x=\arcsin(0.3)$
- $2x=0.3047$
- $x=0.1524$

is the only answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formally, what you can do is to parameterise the expression.

Let $u=2x$

Hence, $sin(u)=0.3$

As you also said, $u=arcsin(0.3)$
which leads to $u=0.3047$ ($4 d.p.$).

Recall $u=2x$

Therefore, $x=0.1524$

However, the function $sin(x)$ is periodic with a period of 2π.
Therefore, if π is added or subtracted to our previous solution, the new value will also be a root of the equation.

In symbols
$x=0.1524 + 2nπ$, for any $n$ belonging to Z.

Comment: Do not forget also the solution $\pi-\arcsin (0.3)$.

Comment: Yeah, true. I was forgetting it.
Your comment implements it already, thus I won't add it. 

Good spot anyway :)

Comment: thanks a lot, good explanation. But didn't you mean adding or subtracting 2$Pi$

Comment: Now I know that because $sin(x)$ is periodic we add $2 pi n$ where n is an integer number. But, why subtracting $pi $ from  $arcsin(0.3)$. Also, can you tell me why my $pi$ doesn't appear as a symbol?

Answer (score 0):

The $\sin$ function is periodic with period $2\pi$, so $\sin(x)=\sin(x+2\pi)$ for all $x$. Therefore there are infinitely many solutions, as you described.

Comment: We also have the solutions $(\pi-\arcsin(0.3))+2k\pi$.

Comment: @gimusi Good point.

Comment: can I say $sin(x)=sin(x+2*n*pi)$.

Comment: @TCHassnaTaha Yes, if $n$ is an integer.

Comment: thank you very much.